# JQuery function "On tick" (Not "On click")

Tags: jquery

Is there any way in JQUERY to trigger a function when a checkbox has been ticked or unticked?

NOTE: I dont want the "click" function because I use another buttons to tick or untick 20 checkboxes at the same time for example. (and in that case I have only 1 click, but really I need to do the "click" function 20 times, one per each 20 checkbox ticked) I don't want make loops because I'm using pagination and another stuff, I'm looking for something more simple as a "onTick" function.

The event is onTick or onUnTick but not "onClick"

Is there any solution?

Many thanks!

##### Solved and 100% working:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I would recomend, as a courtesy to select the answer that bes suits your needs. it is good to keep up your percentage of questions you've chosen an answer for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking maybe onChange would work.

Comment: As simple as effective, u are grand!:

100% working:

$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){});

Answer (score 8):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').bind('change', function(e){
  var jT = $(this);  //jT is a jQuery Object for the current input
    //I.E. 20 'ticks' = 20 calls no looping needed.
  if (jT.is(':checked')){
    //was checked
  } else {
    //was unchecked
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the onchange event. It's fired when the state of the checkbox changes (even programaticaly).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a .change() method that basically handles the onChange event.  You can probably use that.
http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to fade out an item when I clicked my checkbox.

```
$(".done").live("click", function(){

if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
```

$(this).parent().fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
   }else{

$(this).parent().fadeTo('slow', 1);
   }
 });

.done is my checkbox class, to do this for the multiple checkboxes you would set it to your select all.
Ex.

```
$(".selectall").live("click", function(){

if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
```

$(this).parent().fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
   }else{

$(this).parent().fadeTo('slow', 1);
   }
 });

So essentially .is(':checked')) will do what you want.

Edit: Sorry about the code fail - Something went wrong.